# Using manual approximations in limits?

Tags: limits, approximation, limits-without-lhopital

I was going through a question today.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^5 \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x^3}\right\rfloor $$
where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ represents the G.I.F. (floor function).

Without actually trying to solve the question, I tried to use some manual approximations. Like I assumed as $x$ is tending to infinity, It will be a considerably large number but finite. So undoubtedly $$ \frac{1}{x^3} \ll 1 $$

therefore,

$$ \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x^3} \right\rfloor =0 $$

So what we are actually doing is multiplying a very large number but finite $x^5$ to a definite zero. So I concluded that this quantity will tend to zero as $x$ tends to infinity. But the answer is not zero.

What am I missing out here? Thanks.

Comment: What is G.I.F.?

Comment: Your solution seems to be correct. Do they provide a detailed answer? Also, by $x\rightarrow \infty$, do they mean $x\rightarrow +\infty$?

Comment: @A.M. yes by default +infinity.

Comment: @JuanAlfar Floor function/ Greatest integer function (edited)

Comment: You don't need to write $A<<B;$ you can write $A\ll B.$ I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am new to Mathjax. Thanks though :)

Comment: $0\cdot\pm\infty$ isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is indeed $0$. The problem was most likely to find the limit as $x\to-\infty$. If so, the value of the function grows unbounded to positive infinity. If $x\gt1$, then $0\lt1/x^3\lt1$ as the denominator is greater than the numerator. Consequently, the floor function will have that value go to $0$, which is equal to $0$ when multiplied by $x^5$ for any value of $x^5$. Since $x\to\infty$ and $\infty\gt1$, the limit is equal to $0$.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^5\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{x^3}\bigg\rfloor=0$$
However, if it was supposed to be to find the limit as $x\to-\infty$, then we will obtain a different answer. If $x\lt-1$, then the floor function will cause $1/x^3$ to go to $-1$. Firstly, this is because a negative number raised to the third power will also be a negative number. Secondly, $1/x^3$ will be less than zero, but greater than $-1$, so the floor function will have this negative value go to $-1$. Finally, $x^5$ will also be a negative number as a negative number raised to the fifth power is also a negative number. This negative number that is $x^5$ when multiplied by $-1$ will be a positive number. Clearly, $x\to-\infty$ and $-\infty\lt-1$, so the limit grows unbounded to positive infinity.
$$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}x^5\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{x^3}\bigg\rfloor=\infty$$
In response to user Invisible's comment above, $x$ only approaches infinity (positive or negative); it does not equal it (infinity is also not a number), so we are permitted to multiply a constant ($0$ or $-1$) with $x^5$. You are technically correct, however. WolframAlpha confirms both of these limits, as does a careful examination of the graph of the function.